# Verification loop

Tags: c, loops, scanf

This was originally from another program, but this segment will not work the way I need it to and I imagine others may be having trouble as well. Also of note that after the user input is accepted it is used in a while loop.

```
printf("would you like to check another time?(y/n)?");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("% c", &yesno);
while(yesno != 'y' && yesno != 'n')
{
   printf("That was not a valid entry, please re entery your choice.");
   fflush(stdin);
   scanf("% c", &yesno);
}/*End of verification loop*/
```

I want the user to input a character, and after verifying it is either a y or an n, have it go to a while loop where if the character is a y it will continue the program, and if not it will end it.

Comment: what is the way you want it work?

Comment: I want the user to input a character, and after verifying it is either a y or an n, have it go to a while loop where if the character is a y it will continue the program, and if not it will end it.

Comment: [clicky clicky](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_input_and_output)

Comment: @user3259144 Generally you want to put such information in your original question where people can more easily find it. For future reference, when you ask a question, please explain what you *want* your code to do and what it's *actually* doing; this will help people understand what the problem could be and how best to address it.

Comment: @user3259144 You can exit your program in by putting condition `if(yesno == 'n')` then `return` after your `scanf("% c", &yesno);` statement in `while..loop`.Or if input is `y` then automaticaly your `while..loop` break and continue your programme.

Comment: You probably want `" %c"` (space before the `%`, not after).  That skips white space, including newlines, before reading a non-white-space character.

Comment: I added that, but now it keeps exiting regardless of user input input.

Comment: `scanf("% c", &yesno);` ... `% c` should be `%c` without space

Comment: There is a [SO post on why you should not call `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin/2979217#2979217).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    printf("would you like to check another time?(y/n)?\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &yesno);
    while(yesno != 'n' && yesno != 'y')
    {
       printf("That was not a valid entry, please re-enter your choice.\n");
       fflush(stdin);
       scanf("%c", &yesno);

    }
    if (yesno == 'n') return 0; // program terminated here

// else it is automatically 'y' so your program continues here ...
```

**additional**

I just noticed another crucial failure that is affecting your snippet (and i imagine the next lines of codes also )

```
scanf("% c", &yesno); // will not read input
scanf("%c", &yesno); // will read input, there is no space between % and c, it is %c not % c
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `fflush` is defined only for output streams. Calling `fflush` on `stdin` is invokes undefined behaviour. You can use `getchar` function to read and discard extraneous input from the `stdin`.

```
printf("would you like to check another time?(y/n)?");

// read and discard any number of leading whitespace characters
scanf("% c", &yesno); 
char ch;
while(yesno != 'y' && yesno != 'n') {
    // stdout is line buffered. Outputting a newline will immediately flush
    // the output to the console
    printf("That was not a valid entry, please reenter your choice.\n");

    // if the input character is not a newline, then read and discard
    // all character up till and including the newline 
    if(yesno != '\n')
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n');  // note the null statement

    // read the input from the user afresh
    scanf("% c", &yesno);
}
```